# How can I password protect a basic HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, password-protection

What is the simplest possible form of password protection I can use, that doesn't need to be super secure, just keep out the riffraff?  It ideally can be tacked onto a website made of HTML and javascript.

It also needs to work in all browsers (can't rightly allow users to just switch browsers so they can access the contents of the password-protected site!)

Javascript's prompt function seems to be filtered out by IE, so that is out of the question.

Comment: Are you using any particular web server?

Comment: Also, do you have access to protect it on the server? If so, you can do a simple check using a query string in JS; otherwise, your server technology is imperative next to whatever server-side language you are employing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use HTTP basic authentication, as provided by your web server.  In Apache, this is configured simply in your `.htaccess` or vhost configuration.  In IIS, it is a simple GUI option.

Here are the [Apache docs.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#authtype), and here are the [IIS docs.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx?mfr=true) (this is IIS6, but I think it's still the same in IIS7)

A common Apache configuration looks something like this:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd-file
AuthName "String to display in login popup"
AuthType Basic
require user username1 username2
```

Comment: I couldn't remember what it was called.

Comment: didn't know about this, may come in handy. out of curiosity, how secure is this method?

Comment: Easiest to implement, if you dont want much control. @steve You can use the more secure version if needed.

Comment: @steve Here's what Apache has to say about its security: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basiccaveat