# How to handle passwords in JavaScript to hide them from the page source?

Tags: javascript, passwords, mqtt

I'm using [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) in my browser application.
You can set up the broker's credentials in this way:

```
const clientId = '<id>'
const host = 'ws://<address>:<port>'
const topics = ['<topic1>', '<topic2>']

const options = {
  keepalive: 60,
  clientId: clientId,
  protocolId: 'MQTT',
  protocolVersion: 4,
  clean: false,
  qos: 0,
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
  connectTimeout: 30000,
  username: '<user>',
  password: '<pswd>'
}

const client = mqtt.connect(host, options)
```

I don't think this is the correct way since the username and password will be available to anyone, just inspecting the page source.

How should I handle a password in JavaScript to use with other services?

I'm **not** asking about how to protect a page (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543913/var-password-hiding-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542719/how-can-i-password-protect-a-basic-html-page) questions).

Answer (score 1):

As a rule you can't hide anything from the browser (and it's dev tools).

Assuming you have full control over the broker and client then, one approach is to generate short lived (ephemeral) credentials that are requested by the page as a separate request from the base page. These are then used to connect the client and then immediately invalidated (by the broker or what ever backend auth service it is using), so they can't be used again.

The request to generate the ephemeral credentials should be protected by what ever authentication is used to protect the page.

This works because the client/broker only needs to know credentials at the point of starting the connection.

If you are using a 3rd party broker service then you will need to ask them what authentication methods they support, e.g. signed URLs?